# Optimal inference for nonlinear state space models

Tags: kalman-filters, control-systems

When considering a linear-Gaussian state space model, it is often referred that, optimal inference is tractable which is very rare in state space models. When considering a nonlinear state space model, it is said that, *in general* the posterior distribution is intractable, therefore, inference methods should be used to approximate the posterior.

What I would like to ask is that, what is the exceptions for nonlinear state space models? Which nonlinear state space model is tractable analytically? Are there any examples?

PS: For instance, [Doucet says](ftp://ftp.idsa.prd.fr/local/aspi/legland/ref/doucet00b.pdf):

> Given the ﬁltering distribution one can then routinely proceed to
>   ﬁltered point estimates such as the posterior mode or mean of the
>   state. This problem is known as the Bayesian ﬁltering problem or the
>   optimal ﬁltering problem. [...] Except in a few special cases,
>   including linear Gaussian state space models (Kalman ﬁlter) and hidden
>   ﬁnite-state space Markov chains, it is impossible to evaluate these
>   distributions analytically.

To reexpress, I would like to ask that, which *nonlinear* state space model is tractable?

Comment: Is there a specific book or paper that you're referencing? It may be helpful if you mention what it is.

Comment: If you don't get any reasonable answers here, consider requesting migration to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Often nonlinear models are linearized (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearization), which makes them tractable to linear methods.

Comment: Phonon: I couldn't figure out how to migrate questions. Can you give advise? / Jim thanks for that, but I am looking for tractable *nonlinear* models. Linearization is a sort of approximate inference, in particular Extended Kalman Filter is an example of it.

Comment: @DenizAkyildiz If you want it migrated, I can do it for you.

Comment: Phonon, may be now it is proper to migrate this question to the Cross Validated. Thanks.